# Как посмотреть ответ с сервера после отправки POST запроса Angular 7

Tags: angular

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegisterService {
  url = 'http://unfaithfuldate.com/user/api';

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
  sendForm(data){
    return this.http.post(this.url,data).subscribe(data=>data);

   }
}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {RegisterService} from '../services/register.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth-reg',
  templateUrl: './auth-reg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth-reg.component.css']
})
export class AuthRegComponent implements OnInit {

  regForm = new FormGroup({
    username : new FormControl(''),
    email : new FormControl(''),
    password : new FormControl(''),
    gender : new FormControl('')
  });
   response : any;
  constructor(private _registerService:RegisterService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  onRegister(){
   this.response = this._registerService.sendForm(this.regForm.value);
    console.log(this.response);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

В браузере, на панели разработчика(shift+ctrl+i ил F12) есть вкладка сеть. На ней отображаются запросы сделанные от клиента. дальше нужно выбрать вкладку response(ответ) и посмотреть.

Comment: ответ не имеет отношения к поставленному вопросу

Comment: @overthesanity, что значит не имеет? - спросили как посмотреть ответ с сервера, я написал.

Comment: в вопросе приведен код с `console.log`

Comment: @overthesanity он пытается распечатать его, чтоб посмотреть через консоль. автор не указал, что надо его получить в коде. там написано, "как посмотреть". подождем когда он ответит.